# „Всё(-)таки” — с дефисом или без?

Tags: орфография, раздельно-дефис

Всегда считал, что **всё-таки** пишется с дефисом. Читаю эл. книгу и вижу: "всё таки".
Думал, что опечатка — так нет! Тут везде "всё таки". Так как же всё-таки правильно, а?

Comment: Да ладно Вам! В электронной книге, которую я сейчас читаю, столько ошибок и опечаток. В начале постоянно было "я" вместо "и". На протяжении всей книги длинное тире вместо дефиса между словами. Ну и ошибки разнообразные, часть из который в принципе может быть и в нормальной бумажной книге, не знаю уж, хорошо, если маленькая часть или если нету вообще.

Comment: Читать *"...столько ошибок и опечаток!"*. Восклицательный знак забыл, который эмоционально окрашивает слово "столько" и придаёт значение "так много".

Comment: Нельзя использовать слово "нету" вместо слова "нет".

Answer (score 8):

Вы правильно считали. Все-таки  пишется через дефис.

I союз
Употребляется при выражении противопоставления, соответствуя по значению сл.: однако, тем не менее, несмотря на что-либо.

II част.
Употребляется при выражении возражения, противопоставления предыдущему, а также при усилении значения высказываемого или при подчеркивании скрытого противопоставления.

Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000

Но есть частица "все ж таки", которая пишется без дефисов.

В вашем случае в книге, скорее всего, повторяющаяся ошибка.

Answer (score 8):

- Частица ТАКИ пишется через дефис в составе слов **всё-таки** и **так-таки**, а
  также в тех случаях, когда она следует за глаголом, например: **Узнал-таки меня?**

Во всех остальных случаях частица *таки* пишется отдельно, например:
*Я таки думаю кое-что* (М. Горький). И все ж таки я тебя не понимаю.

Answer (score 2):

Частица "таки" пишется через дефис с местоимениями и наречиями: все-таки, так-таки

Answer (score 1):

В словаре Ушакова:

**всё-таки**, союз противительный (часто в сочетании с союзами "и", "а"). Тем не менее, несмотря на что-нибудь, всё же, однако же.
*Что вы ни говорите, все-таки я не поверю. А все-таки я прав.*