# Какую функцию выполняет союз “все-таки” в нижеуказанных предложениях?

Tags: грамматика, союзы

1. Он обязательно победит, все-таки он двукратный чемпион мира.
2. С ним нельзя так поступать, все-таки он твой родной брат.

Comment: Я так понимаю, это усилительная частица. https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/16390/185561

Answer (score 3):

Основываясь на значении слова ***всё-таки***, склоняюсь к тому, что в этих предложениях это **частица**, **усиливающая** сказуемые ***чемпион*** и ***брат***.

> [**ВСЁ-ТАКИ.**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8&all=x) **I. *союз.*** (обычно с союзами: *а, и, но*). Тем не менее, однако, несмотря на что-л. *Не хотела соглашаться и в. согласилась. Хоть вы и много испытали, а в. не разуверились в людях.* **II. *частица.*** Подчёркивает **скрытое противопоставление**. *Как в. приятно приезжать сюда. Может, в. согласишься? А в. он мне нравится. Где же в. мы виделись? Но в. я ему не доверяю.*

В обоих предложениях нельзя заменить "все-таки" на "тем не менее" и другие противительные союзы.

Если мы соглашаемся с тем, что ***всё-таки*** — частица, то эти сложные предложения получаются бессоюзными. Их части взаимодействуют друг с другом на "скрытом" противопоставлении с причинно-следственным оттенком.

Поэтому я бы заменил запятую между простыми предложениями на **тире**:

***Он обязательно победит — все-таки он двукратный чемпион мира.***
***С ним нельзя так поступать — все-таки он твой родной брат.***

Знаю, что если причина содержится во втором из предложений БСП, то после первого ставится двоеточие, но тире — более выразительный знак (тем более что во многих случаях эти два знака конкурируют, и всё чаще отдается предпочтение тире).

Такое решение можно подкрепить примерами из Национального корпуса русского языка:

*Лица он видит лишь тех, кто входит в боковую дверь, — все-таки он не настолько хорошо рассматривал снимки в брошюре, чтобы теперь узнать хоть кого-нибудь из входящих в зал.* [Сергей Носов. Фигурные скобки (2015)]

*Дело даже не в актерских способностях Хоффмана — все-таки он обладатель премии «Оскар».* [Артем Михайлов. Человек-загадка, (2008)]

*На троллейбус он тоже сесть не пожелал, но это понятно ― все-таки он урожденный москвич.*

*Она была совершенно уверена, что он вернется, ― все-таки он очень сильно любил ее тогда ― и ошиблась.* [Татьяна Устинова. Большое зло и мелкие пакости (2003)]

Есть пример и с другой пунктуацией:

*Вероятно, не хватает уже энергии, все-таки он ― самый старший в команде.* [Сергей Долматов. Свистать всех наверх!]

Comment: Александр, вы ведь позволите мне задать вопрос? У частицы "всё-таки" (союзом я бы ее не называла, несмотря на толковый словарь) основное значение - уступительное, то есть она появляется там, где есть противоречивые ситуации. Здесь же на первом плане вроде бы причинное значение. Так в чем заключается скрытое противопоставление, почему уступительная частица  вдруг стала выражать  обычно несвойственное ей значение причины?

Comment: В первой части первого предложения есть сомнение в победе, иначе не было бы второй части. Этому сомнению противостоит аргумент "он все-таки чемпион".

Comment: Во втором — труднее. Причина на лицо. Но опять:  если бы не было второй части, получается, что с ним нельзя так поступать, а с другими можно. И вот тут вступает в дело наша "воинствующая" частица, которая как бы оправдывает подтекст первого посыла. Может, так?

Comment: Александр, вы ведь позволите вас спросить?  А можно ли на заданный вопрос дать ответ в форме одного предложения: Слово  «все-таки» в нижеуказанных предложениях выполняет  функцию…  и имеет значение…  Пожалуйста.

Comment: ...выполняет функцию усиления сказуемых и имеет значение завуалированного возражения.

Answer (score 1):

(1) *Он обязательно победит, **все-таки** он двукратный чемпион мира.*

(2) *С ним нельзя так поступать, **все-таки** он твой родной брат.*

**Ответ:**

В приведенных предложениях частица ***всё-таки*** не является союзом.

Частица является структурным элементом в бессоюзном сложном предложении (БСП).

Частица **подчёркивает скрытое противопоставление** (это ее второе  значение согласно толковому словарю).

Комментарий

1) Основным (первым) значением частицы ***все-таки*** является **уступительное значение**, при этом частицу называть союзом можно только условно.

Она используется в сложных предложениях разного вида, но во всех случаях является **дополнительным структурным элементом**, поясняющим отношения между простыми предложениями в составе сложного.

Например:

***Хотя***  задача оказалась трудной,  **но всё-таки** надо решить ее (СПП, усиление уступительного значения).

*Он догадывался о последствиях, **но всё-таки** сделал по-своему* (ССП, уступительно-противительное значение).

2) Заданные предложения относятся к  БСП.  Так как союза нет, то отношения между простыми предложениями определяет только частица: как уже говорилось, она подчеркивает скрытое противопоставление. **Однако эта формулировка требует пояснения.**

Исходное  **уступительное** значение частицы в БСП сохраняется, но оно становится **скрытым, неявно** выраженным и определяется  только **по контексту.**

При анализе таких предложений просматриваются **два противоположных фактора**, которые могут повлиять на совершение события (отрицательный и положительный). Частица ***всё-таки*** ПОДЧЕРКИВАЕТ положительный фактор (соблюдение причинно-следственных отношений): *он победит, **потому что** он чемпион; с ним нельзя так поступать, **потому что** он брат.*

Отрицательный же фактор и УСТУПИТЕЛЬНОЕ значение частицы прочитывается только в КОНТЕКСТЕ и поэтому остается в тени: *конкуренция большая, **но все-таки** он победит; он виноват, **но всё-таки** с ним нельзя так поступать.*

Comment: Sharon  В вопросе контекста нет, мы ничего не знаем о хитросплетениях мысли автора высказывания, о предыдущем диалоге, если он был. Мы можем только домысливать контекст.  Разъясните, пожалуйста, непонятно вот что: в предложениях с **хотя** оно принимает на себя уступительную функцию, а **все-таки**  перемещается в главное предложение и опять-таки выглядит усилительной. Или я не прав?

Comment: Я немного изменила текст ответа, посмотрите, если интересно. Теперь о ваших замечаниях. В Справочнике по синтаксису я не нашла таких предложений, так что "копать" не пришлось, анализ я делала сама, соответственно, на истину не претендую.  Могу сделать такие выводы. Скрытый контекст просматривается совершенно явно, это детали можно домысливать по-разному. Предложения с тремя ситуациями объясняют семантику, а не грамматику, Грамматика же строится по своим правилам. Усиления я не вижу, потому что нечего усиливать. Частица "все-таки" подчеркивает фактор, влияющий на событие, а не усиливает его.

Comment: Спасибо, интересно. Я дал ответ на вопрос о тире, на который вы мне предлагали ответить.

Comment: Спасибо, обязательно посмотрю. (Кажется, вас об этом просил и автор вопроса.)

Comment: Да, но сначала вы. А от автора я почему-то увидел сообщение только сегодня.

Comment: Да, я помню, любопытно будет взглянуть. Но тогда за вами еще один "должок", но я, конечно, не настаиваю.Так, по возможности и желанию.

Comment: Обидно. Я набирал ответ с ссылками и пр. Черновик светился зеленым, что сохранен. Потом ушел надолго в другие дела - и всё исчезло. Не скажете, время для черновика как-то ограничено? Или всё же я во вневременье попал?

Comment: Как ваш текст, нашелся? Я про черновики ничего не знаю, их раньше не было, но в любом случае электронике не доверяю и поэтому сложный текст составляю на своем компьютере, а потом просто копирую.

Comment: А вы всё правите свой ответ про неполные предложения, теперь придется его снова читать. Кстати, я свой ответ про частицу тоже исправила (постаралась быть ближе к словарю и народу).

Comment: Я перечитал ответ и правило и понял свою ошибку, поэтому исправил. О н/нн писать пока не хочется. Почему-то никто не отвечает. Человек, может, уже получил ответ на другом ресурсе.  После карантина у меня активность поубавится.

Comment: Я про другой ресурс к тому, что часто вижу те же самые вопросы у нас и на Грамоте. Например, вчерашний о "скорее".

Comment: Карантин, да...  Но я почему-то вижу в вашем комментарии другие ключевые слова: не хочется, поубавится. Наверное, правы поэты: то что ярко горит, то быстро гаснет. Где же они, те люди, у которых любовь к языку не зависит от чего-либо. Вообще их что ли нет...

Comment: Скажите, ведь вы здесь давно, раньше ведь было намного больше отвечающих, а сейчас несколько человек. Почему люди пропадают? (риторический вопрос). Пропадает интерес, исчерпывается круг вопросов,  достигается какая-то планка, надоедает однотипность вопросов...

Comment: И интересно, почему вы предложили мне ответить на вопросы, почему вы хотите знать именно мое мнение?

Comment: Интерес к языкам был всегда, со школы, даже хотел поступать на иняз. Учусь каждый день. Про н/нн вопрос интресный для меня, потому что эта область одна из самых трудных (опять же, может, для меня). Пока не хочется - эта площадка забирает очень много времени, а есть насущные дела, ждущие меня.

Comment: Отвечу пока на один вопрос.  Мне кажется, что все люди в какой-то области являются экстрасенсами. У меня такое отношение к языку. Я просто чувствую талант и потенциал людей в этой области. Поэтому так внимательна к ним и так внимательна к вам.  Но кроме таланта, требуется еще характер. Нашему  же правописанию нужен лидер, а он так просто не появится. Это как Пушкин, который мог появиться только в подготовленной среде. У нас же этого нет, мы можем только деградировать, а вперед не двинемся.  И вывод: будь воином Света, если можешь. Возможно, там, где ты оказался, ты один можешь нести этот Свет.

Comment: Замечательно! И грустно, и будоражит. Написал последнее слово... и рассмеялся -  почему-то его вид показался нелепым. Бывает...

Comment: Давайте работать вместе, я верю в вас. И еще, экономьте силы,  вы не можете ответить на всё, вы просто устанете. Пусть другие тоже работают, а вы выбирайте то, что вам важно и интересно, что вас развивает. И не пишите много,  текст должен быть лаконичным и понятным, лучше четко ответить на вопрос. Инфостиль многие критикуют, но для нас он важен. И уровень автора надо представлять: что он вообще может понять.

Comment: Спасибо!  Очень мотивируете! Да, я уже понял кое-то, постепенно войду в свой ритм, азарт стихнет.

Comment: Sharon вы дали ответ, что "всё-таки ПОДЧЕРКИВАЕТ положительный фактор". Для меня это непонятно. Кто фактор? Чемпион и брат? В моем понимании это соответствует ответу Александра о том, что "все-таки"  указывает на "аргумент", "основание" для предыдущего утверждения. Прошу вас дать более конкретный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

**Из комментария**

Sharon вы дали ответ, что "всё-таки ПОДЧЕРКИВАЕТ положительный фактор". Для меня это непонятно. Кто фактор? Чемпион и брат? В моем понимании это соответствует ответу Александра о том, что "все-таки" указывает на "аргумент", "основание" для предыдущего утверждения. Прошу вас дать более конкретный ответ.

Хорошо, я добавлю второй ответ,  **рассматривайте только его**. Тема действительно интересная и сложная, поэтому вопрос заслуживает внимания.

Из ответа Алесандра: Основываясь на значении слова всё-таки, склоняюсь к тому, что в этих предложениях это **частица, усиливающая сказуемые чемпион и брат**.

Представляется, что это не совсем так. Частица фактически является аналогом союза и относится **ко всему предложению**, поясняя отношения между первой и второй частью. Да, можно считать, что вторая часть – это аргумент, но почему потребовался этот аргумент?  Обычно такое происходит, если утверждение в первой части не бесспорно.  И в чем заключается скрытая уступка?  Я попробую ответить на эти вопросы еще раз.

Ответ 2.

В БСП частица ***всё-таки***  формально не является союзом, а считается **структурным элементом**, определяющим отношение между простыми предложениями в составе сложного предложения.

Из словаря: II. **частица**. Подчёркивает скрытое противопоставление. Как в. приятно приезжать сюда. Может, в. согласишься? А в. он мне нравится.  Но в. я ему не доверяю.

1)  ***Всё-таки*** – противительная частица,   в ССП она совместно с союзом обозначает действие, которое совершается **вопреки ожиданию**: *Ему не разрешили, но он все-таки пошел.* Здесь причинно-следственная связь нарушена.

А вот в БСП частица ***всё-таки*** используется при видимом **соблюдении причинно-следственной связи** (что может показаться странным), но при этом указывается на **скрытое противопоставление**.

**А что это значит**? Что означает такое утверждение (из другого ответа): «Их части взаимодействуют друг с другом на "скрытом" противопоставлении с причинно-следственным оттенком». Я не понимаю.

2) Приведем примеры:

*Ты должен помочь им,  **так они**  твои родители.*   Если предыдущее высказывание не требует доказательства, то мы используем причинный союз  ***так как***.

*Ты должен помочь им, всё-таки они твои родственники.* 
Здесь предыдущее утверждение **неочевидно** (может, должен, а может, и нет), поэтому требуется **доказательство** правильности сообщения.

И вот тогда **причина уже приводится как аргумент** (довод, фактор) в пользу правильности высказанного мнения, а другой возможный вариант (никому я ничего не должен) **отрицается, хотя и не называется**. Это и есть скрытое противопоставление.

3) *Он обязательно победит, **так как** он двукратный чемпион мира.* Это неверное суждение, проиграть может и чемпион.

*Он обязательно победит, все-таки он двукратный чемпион мира*.  А здесь во второй части причина называется как  довод (аргумент) в пользу выигрыша.

А в чем скрытое противопоставление? **Давайте его раскроем:** *Он обязательно победит, **все-таки** он двукратный чемпион мира, **хотя** вероятность проигрыша всегда есть.*

Краткий ответ: частица ***всё-таки*** является структурным элементом в БСП, определяющим отношение между простыми предложениями в составе сложного. Частица относится ко второму предложению, в котором приводится обоснованность суждения, высказанного в первом предложении, если это суждение неочевидно.

**Об знаках препинания**

В данном случае при наличии частицы в роли союза не требуются сильные знаки,запятой будет достаточно (как в ССП). Постановка тире – это интонационное (авторское) решение.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon. Добавить нечего.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Вы задали очень интересный вопрос, над ним пришлось подумать. В учебнике по синтаксису такая конструкция не рассматривается, так что проверить правильность ответа по большому счету негде.